# How to remove the '-- Sent with my mu4e' line

Tags: emacs

Recently started using mu4e for email in emacs.  When I compose, I get a line at the bottom by default

```
--
Sent with my mu4e
```

I can always just delete it, but would rather it didn't appear in the signature area in the first place.  What's the command for removing this in my emacs init.el?

Comment: Wow, that's an obnoxious default setting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `mu4e-compose-signature` to modify the signature, or set `mu4e-compose-signature-auto-include` to disable the automatic inclusion of the signature in new messages:

```
(setq mu4e-compose-signature-auto-include nil
      mu4e-compose-signature "")
```